# Gini Impurity, growing random trees in opencv

Tags: opencv, tree, information-retrieval, random-forest

Goal: To add offset-impurity to the split decision of growing trees in openCV.

Currently in opencv random trees, the split is made as following:

```
if( !priors )
{
    int L = 0, R = n1;

    for( i = 0; i < m; i++ )
        rsum2 += (double)rc[i]*rc[i];

    for( i = 0; i < n1 - 1; i++ )
    {
        int idx = responses[sorted_indices[i]];
        int lv, rv;
        L++; R--;
        lv = lc[idx]; rv = rc[idx];
        lsum2 += lv*2 + 1;
        rsum2 -= rv*2 - 1;
        lc[idx] = lv + 1; rc[idx] = rv - 1;

        if( values[i] + epsilon < values[i+1] )
        {
            double val = (lsum2*R + rsum2*L)/((double)L*R);
            if( best_val < val )
            {
                best_val = val;
                best_i = i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Its using the gini impurity.

[image]

Anyone who can explain how the code accomplish this, from what i get it: initially it puts all class counts in the right node, and while moving one instance from right to left and update lsum2 and rsum2 it find the best solution. What i dont get is how p_j^2 is related to lv*2 +1 or rv*2-1.

The real question, if having offsets available and would like to add a split based on the impurity of simularity of offsets. (offsets are direction and distance from center to the current node.

What i have come up with is something like this, and if anyone can point out any flaws it would be good, because atm its not giving good results and im not sure where to start debugging.

```
    //Compute mean
    for(i = 0; i<n1;++i)
    {
        float* point = (float*)(points.data + rstep*sample_idx_src[sorted_indices[i]]);
        meanx[responses[sorted_indices[i]]] += point[0];
        meany[responses[sorted_indices[i]]] += point[1];
    }
    for(i = 0;i<m;++i)
    {
        meanx[i] /= rc0[i];
        meany[i] /= rc0[i];     
    }

    if(!priors)
    {
        int L = 0, R = n1;

        for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
        {
            float* point = (float*)(points.data + rstep*sample_idx_src[sorted_indices[i]]);
            double tmp = point[0] - meanx[responses[sorted_indices[i]]];
            rsum2 += tmp*tmp;
            tmp = point[1] -meany[responses[sorted_indices[i]]];
            rsum2 += tmp*tmp;


        }

        double minDist = DBL_MAX;

        for(i=0;i<n1;++i)
        {
            float* point = (float*)(points.data + rstep*sample_idx_src[sorted_indices[i]]);
            ++L; --R;
            double tmp = point[0] - meanx[responses[sorted_indices[i]]];
            lsum2 += tmp*tmp;
                tmp = point[1] -meany[responses[sorted_indices[i]]];
            lsum2 += tmp*tmp;
                tmp = point[0] -    meanx[responses[sorted_indices[i]]];
            rsum2 -= tmp*tmp;
                tmp = point[1] -meany[responses[sorted_indices[i]]];
            rsum2 -= tmp*tmp;

            if( values[i] + epsilon < values[i+1] )
            {
                double val = (lsum2 + rsum2)/((double)L*R);

                if(val < minDist )
                {
                    minDist = val;
                    best_val = -val;
                    best_i = i;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the Gini coefficient in this case is simple because there are only two groups, left and right. So instead of a large sum `1-sum(pj*pj)` we have `1-pl*pl-pr*pr`. The proportion of items on the left `pl` is the number of items on the left `lv` divided by the total.

Now as we shift the split, `pl*pl` and `pr*pr` change, but not because the total number of items changes. So instead of optimizing `pr` and `pl` (which are floating-point numbers) we optimize `lv and rv` (which are simple counts).

Next, the question why `2*lv+1`. That's simple: we're increasing `lv = lv=1` to optimize `lv*lv`. Now `(lv+1)*(lv+1) - (lv*lv)` (the increase) happens to be `2*lv+1` if you write out all the terms. And the decrease `(rv-1)*(rv-1) - (rv*rv)` happens to be `-2*rv+1` or `-(r*rv+1)`.